# How to calculate net surface area of airplane wing

Tags: integration

i want to calculate the net surface area of ​​an airplane wing, in other words the surface area that will help in generating the lift. I chose a specific airfoil for this, it's NACA 2412, if you don't know what airfoil is, briefly airfoil means the cross-sectional shape of a wing. I will write the necessary values, but I recommend and want to do it with symbols without values (it's up to you).Use the method you want, it doesn't matter if you do it by taking a surface integral or using a different method.

**For NACA 2412:**

Thickness distribution equation is given by:

$$\frac{t}{0.2}\left(0.2969\sqrt{x}-0.126x-0.3516x^{2}+0.2843x^{3}-0.1015x^{4}\right)\left\{0\le x\le1\right\}$$
where t is the maximum thickness as a fraction of the chord. So here t is equal to %12 of chord length

And the camber line equation given by: $$0.125\left(0.8x-x^{2}\right)\ \left\{0\le x\le0.4\right\}$$

$$\frac{1}{18}\left(0.2+0.8x-x^{2}\right)\left\{0.4\le x\le1\right\}$$

For Image $$c_{t}=1.12$$
$$c_{0}=1.63$$
$$b=10$$
where cT and c0 are the tip and root chords and b is the wingspan.

As I said it would be better if you explain step by step using symbols
[image: Geometry of wing]

Comment: This might belong on either physics stack exchange or engineering stack exchange.